# How to run pipeline with constant variables between production and non production

Tags: jenkins, configuration

I have my jenkins pipelines working and all in source code management, within my pipelines I have some constants which are variables that do not change/rarely change, so these would rarely change and the pipelines requires these values, 90% of it doesnt change but I have some that does change based on the environment type (production/pre-production/test etc)

The problem I have right now is that I would like to take thesame code from non-production to production without having to change things like the file server details, as production/non-production use different file servers, as it stands one has to remember to change the file server when promoting code to production, is it possible to have like a configuration file and the pipeline can read the values from the configuration file, I do not want to change the pipelines or make as little changes as possible when my code moves from non-production to production.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps) and create a properties file each in the repositories/branches for production and non-production respectively. Then read and populate the properties from the file in your pipeline during the build.

**Sample server.properties**

```
fileServerUrl=ftp://prod.company.net
fileServerPort=21
// more properties here
```

**Sample Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'production'
    }
    stages {
        stage('prepare-env') {
            script {
                def props = readProperties file: 'server.properties'
                env.fileServerUrl = props.fileServerUrl
                env.fileServerPort = props.fileServerPort
                // more properties here
            }
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            println("INFO: The file server is ${env.fileServerUrl}:${env.fileServerPort}")
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try.